# fetching 'rsync' output with nodejs child_process.exec callback

Tags: node.js, stdout, rsync, stderr

Currently I'm failing to fetch the `rsync` output when I'm calling nodejs `child_process.exec` with a callback-function like in this snippet:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
exec = require('child_process').exec;

cmd = 'rsync -rpz test/test-files/one.txt jloos@test.mygnia.de:~/remote-test/a/b/'
exec(cmd, function(error, stdio, stderr) { 
  sys.print('s: ' + stdio + '\n');
  sys.print('e: ' + stderr + '\n'); 
});
```

I think this is caused by the specific behavior of `rsync`. `rsync` communicates with it's counterpart via terminal. So how can I fetch the messages from `rsync`, if even possible?

When I use `cmd = 'ls -la'` I get the expected output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often stdout is buffered when the program isn't running in a virtual terminal. 
Many languages have a pty module which will trick the program into behaving as though it is running in a terminal.

This provides that functionality for NodeJs;
https://github.com/chjj/pty.js

Keep in mind that rsync may be writing lots of special characters or using something like ncurses to provide the updating status messages, which may make it more difficult to work with the output.